# Disable meteor registration

Tags: javascript, meteor

I want to disable registration from my Meteor app. I'm using the accounts-ui smartpackage.

I tried this:

```
Accounts.config({
  var forbidClientAccountCreation = true;
})
```

but my app server crashes. How can I fix this?

This is using one universal JS file, not one for client and one for server.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`Accounts.config` takes one parameter which is a *javascript hashmap*. You should write it correctly:

```
Accounts.config({
  forbidClientAccountCreation : true
});
```

Comment: Also, about the security of this. Couldn't I just edit the JS file and get an account?

Comment: Yeah, I don't want people to edit it and then magically register :\

Comment: User registration always happen on server, if you modify the code on the client, it will make a request to register your user and will get an "unauthorize" HTTP error, and nothing will be added in your database.

Comment: @mquandalle Can you please provider the source of this information?

Answer (score 18):

I've just ran into this and the answers here aren't completely clear. Accepted answer works for the OP because he's using a single JS file, but if not, place the following code in a file outside the `client` and `server` folders.

```
Accounts.config({
  forbidClientAccountCreation : true
});
```

The reason is that running it on the client will trigger the `accounts-ui`feature of hiding the "Sign up" links and text, and running it on the server will actually forbid new user accounts from being created.

If you only run it on the client, the links and text will be hidden but you can still create an account through the browser's console.

If you only run it on the server, account creation will always fail but you'll still get the associated links and text.

A good place for the code is in the `lib` folder, because anything in that folder will be processed by Meteor both on the server and the client, and also before any other folder. For example, you could place it in `lib/environment.js`.

Comment: i put the code in the /config folder but getting this `Error: Can't set 'forbidClientAccountCreation' more than once
`

Comment: If you're using `useraccounts`, you have to call their own method, since they already call `Accounts.config` internally, see https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/core/issues/25

Comment: I am using this allright but now i get this problem: `Error: signUp route configured but forbidClientAccountCreation set to true!`how can i prevent to setup this route and only set this route when clientaccountcreation is set to false?

Answer (score 1):

Just type next on console:

```
Accounts._loginButtonsSession.set('inSignupFlow', true);
```

and you will see the registration form again.

What I did was to prevent validation of the user creation on server as follows:

```
Accounts.validateNewUser(function (user) {
    return false
});
```